# How to get git branch -a on local to be updated?

Tags: git

I have what seems like an outdated git index. I'm developing on two machines.  On one machine I deleted almost all remote branches with `git push origin :testbranch`  and `git branch -D testbranch`.  This worked great and when I issue a `git branch -a` I get this:

```
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Then I come over to my other machine and do a `git pull`, it doesn't update the index and prints out all the old branches that I deleted on the other machine: `git branch -a`:

```
* master
remotes/origin/add_area_to_locations
remotes/origin/captcha_test
remotes/origin/full_responsive
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/pony_responsive
remotes/origin/shu_responsive
remotes/origin/usmle_cart
remotes/origin/yorgo_responsive
```

So then I google around and am not able to find an index update function per say.  I tried `git update-index --really-refresh`  and `git update-index --refresh` but that didn't appear to do anything.  And just to double check whats on remote I re-cloned the repo and sure enough the repo does not have branches and is clean how I wanted it.

But the question remains - How do I update my local index so it accurately reflects whats in the master origin repo?  I'd hate to have to clone a repo just to clean up the index.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think you understand what the word 'index' means in Git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
git fetch -p
```

> -p, --prune
>
> After fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they
>   are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a
>   --tags option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for
>   example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option), then they
>   are also subject to pruning.

Which means after fetching, it'll remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` usually only fetches the branch you are pulling from, so you would have to pull each branch separately. If you just want to update the remote branches, you should use [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch). With the `--prune` option (or `-p` in short), you can make `git fetch` also get rid of all remote branches that were removed from the remote:

```
git fetch -p
```

So doing that, would get rid of all the branches you removed from the remote.

Finally, about your use of “index”: In Git, the *index* is also called the “staging area”. It’s the intermediary place where changes get added to (using commands like `git add` or `git rm`) which are then included in the next commit. You add changes to the index to *stage them for the next commit* (hence the name “staging area”). All commands with “index” in them likely refer to this, and not to some [lookup index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index#Computer_science).